# What is the usage of '\' and '$' in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, special-characters

As I found (in SQL Server books):

> **`\ (Backslash) (Transact-SQL)`**
>   Breaks a long string constant into two or more lines for readability.

and

> **`SELECT Clause (Transact-SQL)`** ... `$IDENTITY | $ROWGUID`
>   And
>   **`$PARTITION (Transact-SQL)`**
>   Returns the partition number into which a set of partitioning column values would be mapped for any specified partition function.

of usage of `\` and `$` in T-SQL specially SQL Server.

Now, I have a query like this:

```
SELECT \ a, $ b, \11 c, $12 d;
```

That have a valid result like this:

```
a    | b    | c     | d 
-----+------+-------+-------
0.00 | 0.00 | 11.00 | 12.00
```

I think there is something that I can't find it about this characters.

**Edit :**
I found that if a number comes after [currency symbols](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223952%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), SQL Server will remove the defined symbol and store the value as a money data type:

And I think, SQL Server translate a single currency symbol that is the last phrase in a part -these parts are between `+` and `-`- of formula to `0.00` and only at the end of the part like `-$`, `($)`, `(12 + $)`, `($) + 12`, `$ * (12 - $)` or so on, and not `$ + 1`, `2 * $ - 1`. Also I found `$   2` is same as `$2`.

All above behavior is same for `\` that means SQL Server thinks `\` is a currency symbol!!!

Comment: The backslash is not part of a string constant here so the documented behavior does not apply.  The T-SQL parser is not strict so it sometimes allows malformed literals and statements to be interpreted.  Of course, relying on such undocumented behavior is fragile since the behavior may change at any time and break the code.

Comment: "that means SQL Server thinks `\` is a currency symbol!!!" -- Possibly related to the fact that historically, widely used mostly-US-ASCII-compatible Japanese encodings placed the Yen symbol on the code point that would be a backslash in US-ASCII. There are still some fonts that render a backslash as a Yen symbol.

Comment: This can be a starting point for the OP or whoever is willing to answer the question: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/philfactor/2010/07/29/the-killer-backslach-in-tsql/

Comment: @hvd in support of your argument, `$`, `\ `, `€` and `£` seem to be parsed the same way.

Answer (score 7):

I thought to check the datatype and each as you'll notice each returns the datatype money.

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT \ a, $ b, \11 c, $12 d   
)

SELECT  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(a,'baseType') a,
        SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(b,'baseType') b,
        SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(c,'baseType') c,
        SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(d,'baseType') d
FROM CTE
```

Results:

```
a                              b                              c                              d
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
money                          money                          money                          money
```