# SELECT \ FROM AnyTableName

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I tried to explore in SQL. Suddenly saw below query

```
SELECT \ FROM AnyTableName; --give you table name here
```

works fine.
when i try to explore further, the below query, it gives value(s) as 0.00 and datatype as money .

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#A') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #A;
SELECT \ AS A INTO #A;
SELECT A FROM #A;
EXEC TEMPDB..SP_HELP '#A';
```

whats the logic behind SQL Server on this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Someone else wondered the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287368/what-is-the-usage-of-and-in-t-sql) and didn't really get a clear answer but from the research done there I'd say it's just a shortcut way to declare a money datatype, in the same way that adding a period after a number is a shortcut way to use decimals for calculations:

```
SELECT 1.    --returns 1.0 as a decimal number rather than an int
SELECT 1/2  --returns 0 because all operands are ints
SELECT 1/2. --returns 0.5; the addition of a decimal point makes the 2 a decimal instead - whole calc now done with decimals
```

You don't need to write a `.0`, just a period will do, though arguably it's clearer to write `2.0`.

Think of it like a other regular currency sign:

```
SELECT $   --0 money
SELECT ¥1  --1 money
SELECT €.  --0 money
SELECT £.5 --0.5 money
```

etc all get changed to money datatype. Why is it this way for backslash? Well, we can't vouch for what the sql server dev team are thinking but I would propose that some people don't have these signs on their keyboards, so an alternative symbol was also provided that can be used for money if the sqlserver dev team weren't aware of all world currency symbols, or they wanted a standard way to refer to money datatype that specifically wasn't a currency symbol that varies from country to country

Comment: in Select $ query, it results 0.00. we can say it has SELECT $0. Like that for Select \ query, it results 0.00. so that you means it has SELECT \0. $ is currency symbol, so acceptable for this type of calc. is '\' currency symbol, to think it like $?

Comment: Sure. In this case \ is "like a currency symbol", and my theory on it is that sql server dev team thought "as well as supporting all these known currency symbol, lets have a symbol that appears on many keyboards and can be used in the same way, so that it can be used as MONEY shortcut across all the world"

Comment: And then of course, money isn't really an often used data type anyway, I think - so it was a lot of effort from them and not a lot of use by us :)

Comment: yup, may be this can be the reason. This is our assumption only right or this is real? Is there any microsoft doc for '\' reg (backslash)?

Comment: I've not seen any, but equally I haven't ever used the MONEY data type or currency symbols in any query on my professional life and I've been writing software for more than 30 years. I'd put this down as an interesting academic exercise but probably has few real world applications other than to confuse developers :) (i.e. Something to avoid)

Comment: An example of inconsistency in parsing: Generally SQL Server treats blanks (`Char(32)`) and tabs (`Char(9)`) as whitespace, e.g. `select 42 as TheAnswer;` can be written with any mix of blanks or tabs. `select SQL_Variant_Property( 42 , 'basetype' );` returns `int`. Replace the first argument with `\42` or `\ 42` (with a blank) and the result is `money`. Change it to `\   42` with a tab and you will be blessed with `Incorrect syntax near '42'.`. (This is no relation to `select 30 / 3 / 5;` vs. `select 30 / -3 / 5;` which is documented behavior.)